# Power of Gayatri Mantra

Tags: mantras, meditation, gayatri-mantra

Can anybody please tell me about the power of Gayatri Mantra?

I often listen to this and feel something.

Comment: Very good question. This article wud be of some help sir: http://www.sivanandaonline.org/public_html/?cmd=displaysection&section_id=1087. It is written by the saint Sri Swami Sivananda. All the best

Answer (score 8):

The power of the Gayatri mantra is explained in the *Brahma Sutras*, the *Chandogya Upanishad* and the *Brhadaranyaka Upanishad*. The *Brhadaranyaka Upanishad* (V.xiv.1.) says (Swami Madhavananda translator):

> 'Bhumi' (the earth), 'Antariksa' (sky) and 'Dyaus' (heaven) make eight syllables, and the first foot of the Gayatri has eight syllables. So the above three worlds constitute the first foot of the Gayatri. He who knows the first foot of the Gayatri to be such wins as much as there is in those three worlds.

and Sankara's commentary on this verse:

> ...Now the meditation on it [Brahman] as possessing the limiting adjunct of the Gayatri has to be stated; hence the present section. Gayatri is the chief of all metres. It is called Gayatri because, as will be said later on, it protects the organs of those that recite it. Other metres have not this power. The verse Gayatri is identical with the vital force, and the latter is the soul (because it helps in their utterance) of all metres. The vital force, as has been said, is called Ksatra on account of its protecting the body by healing its wounds; (and Gayatri saves the organs if its reciters. So) Gayatri is identical with the vital force. Hence the meditation on Gayatri is being particularly enjoined.

And *Chandogya Upanishad* (III.12.1.) says (Swami Gambhirananda translator):

> Gayatri is verily all these beings that there are. Speech is indeed Gayatri. Speech indeed sings of all these creatures and protects them.

And Sankara's commentary on this verse:

> ...Although there are many metres still, Gayatri is accepted as the door to the knowledge of Brahman because of its pre-eminence. In a sacrifice Gayatri has pre-eminence...Further, since Gayatri is essential to the Brahmanas, and since the great reverence for it is well known, one cannot attain anything higher, including Brahman Itself as spoken of, by rejecting Gayatri which is like one's own mother. Therefore, Brahman is spoken of with the help of the Gayatri.

For further reference see *Brahma Sutras* 1.1.25-27.

Comment: Swami, thanks for this answer.Could you please share your resource link for us,so that as youngsters we can enrich some knowledge.

Comment: @PonmariSubramanian the specific translations of the Chandogya and Brhadaranyaka Upanishads referenced are not on the internet, they are books. If you are in India, they can be purchased here - http://www.mlbd.com/ . If outside India, try Amazon. The Brahma Sutra referenced is available here - http://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brahma-sutras/d/doc62753.html

Answer (score 6):

Power of Gayatri Mantram is explained in [Chapter XXVI- On the narration of Sâvitrî- THE NINTH BOOK of DEVI BHAGAVATAM](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/db/bk09ch26.htm).

> Nârâyana said :-- O Muni! The King As’vapati reigned in Bhadrades’a,
>   rendering his enemies powerless and making his friends painless. He
>   had a queen very religious; her name was Mâlatî; She was like a second
>   Laksmî. She was barren; and desirous of an issue, She under the
>   instruction of Vas’istha, duly worshipped Sâvitrî with devotion. But
>   She did not receive any vision nor any command; therefore She returned
>   home with a grievous heart. Seeing her sorry, the king consoled her
>   with good words and himself accompanied her to Puskara with a view to
>   perform Tapas to Sâvitrî with devotion and, being self-controlled,
>   practised tapasyâ for one hundred years. Still he could not see
>   Sâvitrî, but voice came to him. An incorporeal, celestial voice
>   reached his ears :-- “Perform Japam (repeat) ten lakhs of Gâyatrî
>   Mantram.” At this moment Parâsara came up there. The king bowed down
>   to him.
>
> *The Muni said :-- O King! One japa of Gâyatrî, destroys the day's sins.
>   Ten Japams of Gâyatrî destroy day and night’s sins. One hundred
>   Gâyatrî Japams destroy one month’s sins. One thousand Japams destroy
>   one year’s sins. One lakh Gâyatrî Japams destroy the sins of the
>   present birth and ten lakh Gâyatrî Japams destroy the sins of other
>   births. One hundred lakhs of Japams destroy the sins of all the
>   births. If ten times that (i.e., 1,000 lakhs) be done, then liberation
>   is obtained.*

Answer (score 0):

Becoming radiant Divine light is the greatest benefit, but if that’s not enough for you, or you think it’s too far away, along the path to Divinity there are many other benefits that you can enjoy sooner.

Some of the powers from Gayatri mantra:

- Removes obstacles from your life
- Protects you from danger
- Brightens you mind
- Dispels ignorance
- Improves communication abilities
- Opens your psychic vision
- Brings direct knowledge of the eternal
  truths
  You can call these are some few powers we can attain as per from my resources. Still there are many powerful gains through this mantra.

Reference: https://www.speakingtree.in/blog/gayatri-mantra-meaning-advance-benefits-and-power

Comment: +1, Good answer sir, could you please mention what your sources are if that's ok, so that it would be easier for others to refer those if required?

Comment: Here is my one of the source I have searched http://www.speakingtree.in/blog/gayatri-mantra-meaning-advance-benefits-and-power

Comment: I downvoted your answer. First, because the Sanskrit terms are transliterated wrong in that blog, second: the author of that article emits speculation about 7 chakras and puts extra verses inside mantra just for his own unknown aim. I believe we must search references in textual traditional sources and not in new-age like blogs and so on. I mind to keep Gayatri clear as in tradition and I don't trust someone who adds words to such a great mantra.

Comment: Hi user3344236. The questioner just asked about the changes that happened to him when he heard that mantra. He strongly agreed that something happened to him through this mantra. And that's the reason he questioned them.

Comment: You're encouraged to cite scriptural quotes since blogs are often not reliable.